# How to send data to server React Native |

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, react-native

I made a react native project and I got a prolem
I try to send a data to my server but the server didn't get the data. 
I already made a code but its not work properly
and here's my code

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {
      e :"",
    }

}

componentWillMount(){
    this.UserLoginFunction(View);
}
UserLoginFunction = () =>{
fetch('https://sen.000webhostapp.com/Profile.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

    em: this.state.e,

  })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
          Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
      }).catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert(error);
      });


  }



render() {
      AsyncStorage.multiGet(['email']).then((data) => {
        let email = data[0][1];

        if (email !== null){
            this.setState({ 
                e:email
            });
        }



     });
return()
}
```

and the .php file  is

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$obj = json_decode($json,true);

$u = $obj['em'];
echo json_encode($u);
```

but the respond is nothing I got null. can anyone solve this?

Comment: `e :"",` ? What are you sending?

Comment: `echo json_encode($u);`. Change to `echo "json: " . $json;`. What do you get?

Comment: @greenapps its an initial for `e`

Comment: after change I got error `expected dynamic type string  but had type  object`

Comment: Then tell what you are sending! And where did you get that error? You should not tread the response as json then of course. Just display the json text in an alert.